# Searching through an ArrayList of Strings to find text

Tags: java

This is what I have so far but I don't now what to do next. The question is as follows (sorry the coding is not all appearing in one box):
Implement a method

```
public void search (String searchString) { }
```

to iterate through the notes ArrayList until it finds a note that contains the searchString. It should then print either the item found or the message "String not found". When testing check for a String that is in the list and for one that isn't.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * A class to maintain an arbitrarily long list of notes.
 * Notes are numbered for external reference by a human user.
 * In this version, note numbers start at 0.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kolling.
 * @version 2008.03.30
 */
public class Notebook
{

// Storage for an arbitrary number of notes.
private ArrayList<String> notes;

/**
 * Perform any initialization that is required for the
 * notebook.
 */
public Notebook()
{
    notes = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
 * Store a new note into the notebook.
 * @param note The note to be stored.
 */
public void storeNote(String note)
{
    notes.add(note);
}

/**
 * @return The number of notes currently in the notebook.
 */
public int numberOfNotes()
{
    return notes.size();
}

/**
 * Show a note.
 * @param noteNumber The number of the note to be shown.
 */
public void showNote(int noteNumber)
{
    if(noteNumber < 0) {
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
        System.out.println("invalid index given");
    }
    else if(noteNumber < numberOfNotes()) {
        // This is a valid note number, so we can print it.
        System.out.println(notes.get(noteNumber));
    }
    else {
         System.out.println("there are fewer items in the notebook than that");
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
    }
}

public void removeNote(int noteNumber)
{
    if(noteNumber < 0) {
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
         System.out.println("invalid index given");
    }
    else if(noteNumber < numberOfNotes()) {
        // This is a valid note number.
        notes.remove(noteNumber);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("there are fewer items in the notebook than that");
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
    }
}

public void multiplesOfFive()
{

    int i = 10;
    while(i < 100) 
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        i = i + 5;
    }
}

public int sum(int a, int b)
{

    int index = a;
    int result = 0;
    while(index <= b) 
    {
        result = result + index;
        index = index + 1;
    }
    return result;
}

public int product(int a, int b)
{

    int index = a;
    int result = 1;
    while(index <= b) 
    {
        result = result * index;
        index = index + 1;
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean 
    isPrime (int n)
    {
       if (n<=1)return false;
       if (n==2) return true;
       for (int i = 2;i<=n-1;i++)
       {
         if (n%i==0)return false;
       }
       return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: What's with the sum, product, isPrime, etc?

Comment: The Notebook class is most likely a base that the instructor provided on/with which a series of assignments will be performed

Answer (score 1):

two ideas to consider:

1. When you compose your search method, consider utilizing the [`contains`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method in the String class as you iterate (see Kaleb Brasee's post).
2. ensure that you handle the case when a `null` is passed in as the search param.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the new [for-each style loops](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate over the List of notes:

```
for (String string : notes) {
    // This will loop over all the Strings in the notes List.
    // Perform your logic here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not in alphabetical order you need to loop through the list comparing each string against the search string. Once you find a match you can break the loop (using a return true (or the string) would be the easiest way) then outside the loop you can place a return false to signify that a match was not found.

**Some methods you will need to use**:
        ***ArrayList***:

- size() - gives you the size of the list so you know when you have reached the end
- get( int index ) - returns the item in the list at the specified index

***String:***

- equals( String cmp ) - compares 2 strings and returns an int

It would be good to become familiar with the [Java API](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/) so that you can find methods and their return values.

If the list is in alphabetical order there are more efficient ways to search.